# Which open source frameworks/libraries you folks suggest for Model Based Testing?

Tags: java, testing

Are there any popular frameworks for MBT **in Java**? Is anyone of you using MBT technique?

Comment: I also found another one which looks pretty decent http://graphwalker.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Groovy with ModelJUnit](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Model-based+testing+using+ModelJUnit)

From the site:

> [ModelJUnit](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~marku/mbt/modeljunit/) is a Java library that extends [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) to support model-based testing.

Answer (score 2):

One way of approaching model based testing is to build a known-good implementation and compare against that.  One of the best strategies for doing this is to use a higher-level language so that a short and concise implementation is easy to read and reason about.

I've had great success using [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org) and [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) to do model-based testing of a query evaluation.  I represented the query language as a Haskell data type, and then simply made this an instance of `Arbitrary`.  Once that was done, QuickCheck could generate infinite numbers of queries, which I could then evaluate against both the server under test and my model implementation.

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [Scala-Check](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/) might allow you to do the same sort of thing on the JVM.

As a quick example of how this might be used, here's a quick and dirty example:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Monad (liftM,liftM2)

-- An simple expression data type.
-- Expression is either (Add X Y, Minus X Y, Multiply X Y or just a plain value)
-- where X and Y are further expressions
data Expression = Add Expression Expression
                | Minus Expression Expression
                | Multiply Expression Expression
                | Value Int
                  deriving Show

-- This is my model-based approach, high level 
evaluate :: Expression -> Int                  
evaluate (Value x) = x
evaluate (Add lhs rhs) = evaluate lhs + evaluate rhs
evaluate (Minus lhs rhs) = evaluate lhs - evaluate rhs
evaluate (Multiply lhs rhs) = evaluate lhs * evaluate rhs
```

After this I have a known good implementation of a simple model.  Just by inspecting the code I can be reasonable sure that this does what I think it should do.  Now I can use `Arbitrary` to generate arbitrarily complicated expressions.  The weightings below indicate the frequency (so 70 percent of the generated expressions will be `Value` and 10 percent will be arbitrary `Add` statements and so on )

```
instance Arbitrary Expression where
    arbitrary = frequency [
      (70,liftM Value arbitrary)
    , (10,liftM2 Add arbitrary arbitrary)
    , (10,liftM2 Minus arbitrary arbitrary)
    , (10,liftM2 Multiply arbitrary arbitrary)
    ]
```

This definition gives QuickCheck the power to create me arbitrary expressions.  For example:

```
> sample (arbitrary :: Gen Expression)
Multiply (Value 1) (Value 0)
Value 1
Add (Value (-3)) (Add (Value (-1)) (Minus (Value 3) (Value 0)))
Value (-4)
Value (-19)
Add (Value (-49)) (Value (-55))
Minus (Value 50) (Value 103)
Value 210
Value (-172)
Value (-907)
Value (-2703)
```

I think this is already pretty cool (but maybe I'm just weird).  The real powerful bit is that now I can specify an invariant that holds over all generated values

```
prop_testAgainstModel :: Expression -> Bool
prop_testAgainstModel expr = evaluate expr == evaluate' expr
```

Where we assume that `evaluate'` is my super-complicated way of evaluating things that I want to verify against my model.  QuickCheck will then generate lots of arbitrary expressions and try to disprove my assertion.

Here's an example run against one of my attempts to produce a more complicate evaluate function.

```
> quickCheck prop_testAgainstModel
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 28 tests):  
Multiply (Value (-53758)) (Value 125360)
```

I used this approach to test an external server written in C++.  The Haskell model implementation was maybe a few 100 lines of code and I could compare this against the results of the web service with not much more code than that above.

Comment: I am looking for something in Java or a dynamic vm language

Comment: Perhaps you could achieve the same sort of approach using Scala and it's version of QuickCheck (http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/)

Comment: can you explain how QuickCheck helps in MBT? can i describe to it the state transition so that it can generate the tests?

Comment: I tried to put a little bit more of a description in the code, hopefully that explains what I mean a bit clearer.

Comment: thans jeff..i think i will stick with ModelJUnit for now